# Run (install) go code when GOPATH is inferred

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I just installed [Go extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukehoban.Go) for Vscode and set `"go.inferGopath": true`, as explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension#gopath-from-goinfergopath-setting).
With autobuild on save my code builds, `GOPATH` is inferred correctly. 
Is there a way to run my code (`go install`) with the inferred `GOPATH` from vscode? When running any Go command from vscode terminal it uses system `GOPATH` from go env.

Answer (score 0):

`go install` will always use the go environment settings, unless you modify the go toolchain. On Linux, you can use the `env` command to change environment variables for the execution of a single command; on Windows, you can use `SET` to change environment variables for only the current shell session.

Comment: I know that go install use the environment variables. My question is how can I take advantage of the inferred `GOPATH` to create an executable of my code? What's the point of having an inferred `GOPATH` and not being able to run your code unless you manually set the `GOPATH` to be able to create that executable? I think I'm missing something...

Comment: You can't, unless the plugin providing the inferred `GOPATH` also provides some particular facility for doing so. `go install` uses the environment variables exclusively, there is no other mechanism.

Comment: Exactly. My question is more about if the `GO` extension provide this functionality or how I can achieve that. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: And the answer would appear to be no, and you can achieve it using temporary environment variables, as indicated in the answer. Most `GOPATH` shenanigans do more harm than good; just use a normal `GOPATH` and put your projects under it and everything will work as expected.